# Firebase user tracking when signing in

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am completely new to Firebase, We currently have auth0 set up for our app authentication.

We use firebase analytics for user tracking, What we found was that when we are tracking users we lose the user jounrey when they come to sign in to our app, because we have no way of integrating firebase with auth0.

For instance when a user comes froma facebook campaign... we can track all the way to the sign in but we then lose the information and cannot track any longer. This seems to be an issue with Auth0..

Can Firebase handle this.. id assume it can becuase its part of its service?

Comment: anyone got any ideas?